# Rails registration like Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, registration

I'm about to start my first rails app! :)

How do I make a simple registration like [Heroku](http://heroku.com)? The user just enters their email, then they get a confirmation email, then they fill out some profile info.

Remember, I have about zero Rails experience. Maybe I'm biting off more than I can chew...

Thoughts?

*Edit*
@Apneadiving: I'm getting this error when starting webrick after following your tutorial: `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
...< 'password not match' password != password_confirmation`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use devise and the nice tutorial [here](http://blog.devinterface.com/2011/05/two-step-signup-with-devise/).

Comment: @Kevin Brown:doesn't it answer? I see you're cloning an app using devise in another question.

Comment: I'm just fooling around--since I'm starting from knowing almost nothing about rails, I figure I should get comfortable with git and just generally setting up an app before actually beginning anything serious.  See my edit?